# Proving the cardinality of a more involved set

Tags: isabelle

Supposing I have a set involving three conjunctions `{k::nat. 2<k ∧ k ≤ 7 ∧ gcd 3 k = 2}`.

How can I prove in Isabelle that the cardinality of this set is 1  ? (Namely only k=6 has gcd 3 6 = 2.) I.e., how can I prove `lemma a_set : "card {k::nat. 2<k ∧ k ≤ 7 ∧ gcd 3 k = 2} = 1"` ?

Using `sledgehammer` (or `try`) again doesn't yield results - I find it very difficult to find what exactly I need to give the proof methods to make them able to to the proof. (Even removing, e.g. `gcd 3 k = 2`, doesn't make it amenable to `auto` or `sledgehammer`.)

Comment: `nitpick` also finds a counter example. It just shows "Empty assignment" which is not very useful. But it can be an indication that your lemma might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposition is incorrect. The set you described is actually empty, as `gcd 3 6 = 3`. Sledgehammer can prove that the cardinality is zero without problems, although the resulting proof is again a bit ugly, as is often the case with Sledgehammer proofs:

```
lemma "card {k::nat. 2<k ∧ k ≤ 7 ∧ gcd 3 k = 2} = 0"
  by (metis (mono_tags, lifting) card.empty coprime_Suc_nat 
        empty_Collect_eq eval_nat_numeral(3) gcd_nat.left_idem 
        numeral_One numeral_eq_iff semiring_norm(85))
```

Let's do it by hand, just to illustrate how to do it. These sorts of proofs do tend to get a little ugly, especially when you don't know the system well.

```
lemma "{k::nat. 2<k ∧ k ≤ 7 ∧ gcd 3 k = 2} = {}"
proof safe
  fix x :: nat
  assume "x > 2" "x ≤ 7" "gcd 3 x = 2"
  from ‹x > 2› and ‹x ≤ 7› have "x = 3 ∨ x = 4 ∨ x = 5 ∨ x = 6 ∨ x = 7" by auto
  with ‹gcd 3 x = 2› show "x ∈ {}" by (auto simp: gcd_non_0_nat)
qed
```

Another, much simpler way (but also perhaps more dubious one) would be to use `eval`. This uses the code generator as an oracle, i.e. it compiles the expression to ML code, compiles it, runs it, looks if the result is `True`, and then accepts this as a theorem without going through the Isabelle kernel like for normal proofs. One should think twice before using this, in my opinion, but for toy examples, it is perfectly all right:

```
lemma "card {k::nat. 2<k ∧ k ≤ 7 ∧ gcd 3 k = 2} = 0"
proof -
  have "{k::nat. 2<k ∧ k ≤ 7 ∧ gcd 3 k = 2} = Set.filter (λk. gcd 3 k = 2) {2<..7}"
    by (simp add: Set.filter_def)
  also have "card … = 0" by eval
  finally show ?thesis .
qed
```

Note that I had to massage the set a bit first (use `Set.filter` instead of the set comprehension) in order for `eval` to accept it. (Code generation can be a bit tricky)

**UPDATE:**

For the other statement from the comments, the proof has to look like this:

```
lemma "{k::nat. 0<k ∧ k ≤ 5 ∧ gcd 5 k = 1} = {1,2,3,4}"
proof (intro equalityI subsetI)
  fix x :: nat
  assume x: "x ∈ {k. 0 < k ∧ k ≤ 5 ∧ coprime 5 k}"
  from x have "x = 1 ∨ x = 2 ∨ x = 3 ∨ x = 4 ∨ x = 5" by auto
  with x show "x ∈ {1,2,3,4}" by (auto simp: gcd_non_0_nat)
qed (auto simp: gcd_non_0_nat)
```

The reason why this looks so different is because the right-hand side of the goal is no longer simply `{}`, so `safe` behaves differently and generates a pretty complicated mess of subgoals (just look at the proof state after the `proof safe`). With `intro equalityI subsetI`, we essentially just say that we want to prove that `A = B` by proving `a ∈ A ⟹ a ∈ B` and the other way round for arbitrary `a`. This is probably more robust than `safe`.

Comment: What an illuminating answer! (I'm still surprised how "volatile" Sledgehammer is - at first it didn't work even with the correct formulation of the lemma, I had to restart Isabelle to get it workong. Do you know how to set the time limit to 60 seconds instead of the default 30 seconds, before the ATPs are timed out ?)

Comment: And what is the reason that in the proof by hand you use `safe` instead if `-` ?

Comment: If I play a bit around with the numbers in your structured proof and go for, e.g. `lemma "{k::nat. 0<k ∧ k ≤ 5 ∧ gcd 5 k = 1} = {1,2,3,4}"` and adapt your proof accordingly, I get stuck in the last line, which then reads `with ‹gcd 5 x = 1› show "x ∈ {1,2,3,4} by ???` where I have to find a suitable replacement for `gcd_non_0_nat`. I suppose it's `gcd_1_nat`, but it doesn't work. Could I use somehow have Sledgehammer at this point to finish the proof or find `gcd_1_nat` ? (If I just try Sledgehammer, it returns `Illegal application of proof command in "chain" mode`.)

Comment: `gcd_non_0_nat` is still applicable. That rule is just to evaluate expressions like `gcd 5 2`; it eventually runs the Euclidean algorithm by reducing one argument with `mod` again and again until reaching 0. The reason why your proof fails is probably something different; I updated my answer.

Comment: After `proof`, you must give an initial proof method that is applied to transform the goal state. Often, this is either something like `cases` or `induction`, but even more often it is simply `-`, which does nothing at all. I used `safe` here, which applies all ‘safe’ introduction rules (i.e. that have been declared as `intro!:`. For instance, it strips away all kinds of logical connectives and quantifiers; unfortunately, if you have a goal like `x ∈ {1,2}`, it splits that into the unwieldy `x ≠ 1 ⟹ x ≠ 2 ⟹ x ∈ {}`.